# case statement not working as expected in power BI

Tags: sql, reporting-services, powerbi, ssms, powerquery

I have a table in ssms and on using the case statement, it is working as expected as shown:

[ssms_case_statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3xZQ.png)

But doing the same thing in Power BI with adding columns, conditional statement, it is not working as expected. The screenshot is below. I am stuck here. Please help me out.
[Power BI case statement issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ6XN.png)

[image: casesql_BI.PNG]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 then [Value] * 100 else [Value]
```